# Dropping Unique index and setting same fields to be the Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, indexing, composite-primary-key

I have a 5GB that has 3 columns as a unique (non-clustered) index. I want to promote these three to be the new primary key (clustered). Should I drop this index before change the PK?

Also I am planning on dropping this index after I change the PK.

The types of the three fields are

```
field1: int
field2: int
field3: char(7)
```

**Update:**
Change the word promoting to dropping and setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *promote* an existing index to primary key (or anything else).

You'll have to **drop** the unique index first, **then** create a new primary key constraint on those three columns (which will automatically create the primary key index)

Comment: Should I drop first then create new pk, or create new pk then drop index?

Comment: @JamesMohler: doesn't really matter, I would say. I would probably drop the existing index first - just to avoid any possible unexpected side-effects of having the same rows in two indices...